# NullReferenceException in PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Since I have changed my hosting to ASP.NET 4.0 Web Form and IIS7 Integrated Mode, my website usually has the below error:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception
>   error) +197
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb) +89
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +189

However, the website works fine. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: Anyone solve this problem? I'm seeing this:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at 
System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)   at 
System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) at 
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Answer (score 12):

As Gisli Konrao posted, in a comment, it is due to the fact that you have a custom event handler wired up in the ASP.NET MVC 4 application.

In my case, I had:

```
this.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(MvcApplication_BeginRequest);
```

After commenting out this statement, the problem was fixed (ASP.NET wires up these events on the background, so just defining it will make it work).

Comment: when using Windows Authentication, in my case and adding this:
`this.AuthenticateRequest += vcApplication_AuthenticateRequest;`

Answer (score 7):

I solved this by moving my BeginRequest event observer hook-up code into the Global.asax (MvcApplication) constructor.

I also filed another connect bug since a similar one was closed as not reproducible, yet this error seems to be all over forums on the web.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/788481/iis-express-with-vs2012-null-ref-when-attaching-handler-to-httpapplication-beginrequest

A null ref is never right. We shouldn't see null refs from an MS API.

Answer (score 7):

Put the code for wiring up the events and initialization stuff in an overridden Init() method of the HttpApplication class. That's supposed to fire after the essential ASP.NET things are all setup.

Comment: This was the correct fix for me. I had event handlers (for logging purposes) in `Application_Start`; moving them to `Init` fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have any custom HttpModules in your application? This happened to me when I had and HttpModule adding application events on Init. Try disabling your custom HttpModule and see if you application gets past this point. If it does, then it's because of the difference between how HttpModule work in .Net 3.5 and .Net 4.0.

Comment: Thank for your answer Gisli, I had removed all HttpModule from my project by it still not solve. Finally, I changed IIS from Integrated to Classic and change routing URL to have extension (.aspx) now it work fine.

Comment: are you doing something similar to this then: http://forums.asp.net/t/1327102.aspx/1 ? (Setting application level events programatically on Application Start instead of just creating functions called Application_<EventName> in your Application class)