# Create C# code analysis rule that generates compiler error

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, code-analysis

From time to time, I encounter annoying bugs in the .NET framework that the compiler cannot clearly point out at both compile time and runtime. [This for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11929557/458991).

It states that if you wire up the `MvcApplication.BeginRequest` manually in `Application_Start` from Global.asax.cs, you'll get a `NullReferenceException` in `System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate`.

Since there is no clear way to relate the error to the cause, it would be nice to be able to write something that states that if you wire up event `MvcApplication.BeginRequest` from `MvcApplication.Application_Start`, to throw an compile time error, forcing you to remove it and explain why.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom FxCop rule which checks if the handler is wired up as you said and include that rule in your code analysis ruleset. Check out the rule [CA2001](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385973%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), it does something similar to what you want to achieve.

For information on implementing custom FxCop rules see http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/index.html.

Comment: it would be awesome if MS would add this as a CA2001 rule into the compiler, but I don't see a posability to write one myself here. I could look into FxCop, but are you sure this specific case is possible? It seems like something that would be quite hard to define? Any pointers to a FxCop rule that does something similar would be apreciated (tried to search, but was unable to find such a rule).

Comment: I written only simple FxCop rules, but I think it should be possible. Many standard rules are very complex (such as checking if IDisposable is implemented correctly). Try using a decompiler on the default rules assemblies. This should give you some ideas how on how to implement your rule.