# null reference in pipeline for PostAuthenticateRequest in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, claims-based-identity

I am trying to follow the example from Brock Allen on how to add custom roles to windows roles using claims.(http://brockallen.com/2013/01/17/adding-custom-roles-to-windows-roles-in-asp-net-using-claims/)  at the moment, just plugging in the code from their example i get the following error. I am trying this with clean new MVC 5 project that only has Microsoft.IdentityModel added.  What am i missing that would cause this error?

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   System.Web.PipelineModuleStepContainer.GetStepArray(RequestNotification
>   notification, Boolean isPostEvent) +22
>   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error) +1324
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb) +95
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +186

here is the code in my global.asax.cs file

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        PostAuthenticateRequest += WebApiApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest;
    }

    void WebApiApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            var id = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First();
            id.AddClaim(new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/gender", "potato"));

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

after more digging it seems to be magic or auto event wrap that makes this work.  i don't have to declare an event handler.

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }

        void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {  
                var id = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First();   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason why your previous code (event_handler += method) wasn't working, is that that in the `Application_Start` method, the event handler modules haven't all been loaded yet. 
ASP.NET knows to use the convention of "`_EventHandlerMethod`" to wire up your methods correctly after the event handler module has been loaded.
If you wanted to call the methods something else, you would do it in `Init()` method.

Comment: Ok, I get it now.  I have to make the first segment Application regardless of my class name. In my case I implemented Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute

Comment: @MisterHux do you know where's the documentation that states that if you explicitly register the event handlers you end up in a situation where the modules haven't all been loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Late answer! I have got the same problem. I solved it by hooking the event in the constructor instead of Application_Start.
by [Luke Puplett](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005646/nullreferenceexception-in-pipelinestepmanager-resumesteps)

Comment: I like Michael solution better

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks!